# how to insert foreign key in a table

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys, primary-key

I just want to make sure that I understand `PRIMARY` and `FOREIGN` key relation before searching for some finished answers on the internet.

Let's say this:

We have table `CITY(ID-PK,CODE,NAME)` and we have table `PERSON(ID-PK,NAME,LASTNAME,CITY_ID-FK)`

I'm confused, if in this case user needs to enter a foreign key in the table person? If not how know which city needs to be applied to the user? If user needs to enter a foreign key why to have it then because in that way we are leaving a lot of space for manipulation from the user side (etc. wrong ID input...)

How to connect those two tables? What would be a recognizable reference to connect? Or in this example user needs to input a foreign key?

I'm using ORACLE database. I would appreciate any explanation and example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by 'wrong ID input', but I'll assume you mean an ID that that isn't valid, rather than just a mistake (like saying someone is in a different city to where they really are).

The foreign key constraint means that the value they enter in the `person` table for `city_id` **has** to exist as a primary key in the `city` table. They cannot put any old value in as a `city_id`, only valid values. And the corresponding `city` row cannot then be deleted without either removing/changing the reference in the `person` table (e.g. updating to a different valid value), or - unlikely in this case - cascading the delete so that any `person` records for the `city` are deleted.

So lets say you create your tables as:

```
create table city (id number primary key, code varchar2(2), name varchar2(30));

create table person (id number, name varchar2(30), last_name varchar2(30),
    city_id number not null references city(id));
```

You have three records in your `city` table:

```
insert into city (id, name) values (1, 'New York');
insert into city (id, name) values (2, 'London');
insert into city (id, name) values (3, 'Paris');
```

Then you can add a `person` who lives in New York by including the ID of that city:

```
insert into person (id, name, last_name, city_id)
values (1, 'Michael', 'Bloomberg', 1);
```

([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1aca5/1))

You aren't denormalising the data in the matching `city` record, so if it New York decided to change its name back to New Amsterdam, say, that would be a single update to the `city` record and you wouldn't have to touch any `person` records for people in that city.

If you tried to delete the `city` record for New York, you'd get an error (ORA-02292) saying that a child record existed. You could update the `person` record to have a `city_id` of 2 or 3, and would then be able to delete New York. The idea is that you can't do this by accident and leave orphaned data behind - a `person_id` pointing to a `city` that no longer exists.

If you tried to create a `person` record with a `city_id` value that doesn't match a `city.id` value:

```
insert into person (id, name, last_name, city_id)
values (2, 'Elvis', 'Presley', 4);
```

... then you'd get an error (ORA-02291) that the parent key - that is, a matching `id` value in the `city` tables - doesn't exist.

You can read more about foreign keys in [the database concepts guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/datainte.htm#CHDIIGBG).

Comment: so basically I need to insert a foreign key in the table? what got me confused is that I thought that I need to somehow dynamically insert foreign key and I have no reference to it because I can't determine from which city is certain person. is that correct?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about not being able to determine which city a person is from. That has to be in your input data, somehow. If you know they're from London, you'd look up the `city.id` that matches that name, and use that as the `person.city_id` value. If you don't know the city, the `city_id` would have to be nullable and you'd leave it blank. I think I'm missing something though...

Comment: no Alex you are answering my questions, but I need to form them better :) my simplify question would be: Does user inputs a foreign key in this example?

Answer (score 1):

With whis code you could add a constraint on the Person table to have the foreign key of the City table

```
alter table PERSON
add constraint CONSTR_PERSON_CITY
foreign key (CITY_ID-FK)
references CITY (ID-PK);
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind if Person table City_ID has a value/s that do not exist in City table, trying to create a constraint will give you an error.  Took me a while to figure out why.