# insert data into table having foreign key

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have two tables linked as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `property_details`(
    id INT NOT NULL,
    `name` VARCHAR(100),
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
)
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE `hilton`(
`property_id` INT NOT NULL,
`start_date` DATE DEFAULT NULL,
`end_date` DATE DEFAULT NULL,
`msg` VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL, 
`sunday` INT(11),
`monday` INT(11),
`tuesday` INT(11),
`wednesday` INT(11),
`thursday` INT(11),
`friday` INT(11),
`saturday` INT(11),
FOREIGN KEY(property_id) REFERENCES property_details(id)
)
```

I insert data in `property_details` table. eg..

```
INSERT INTO property_details(`id`,`name`) VALUES ('1','Hilton');
```

Now, i want to enter data in `hilton` table. Can u tell me how should i write query for entering data in `hilton` table?

Comment: exactly like how you inserted data into the property_detail table!

Comment: I have mentioned the query for entering data in property_details table

Comment: There is no difference between the insert statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You firstly have to insert data in the PrimaryKey Table (`property_details`), so that there is a `PrimaryKey` you can reference in the `ForeignKey` Table (`hilton`).

1)

```
INSERT INTO property_details('id','name') VALUES ('1','Hilton');
```

2)

```
INSERT INTO hilton ('property_id',...) VALUES ('1',...);
```

Comment: This does not work! I am getting following error: "
INSERT INTO hilton(`property_id`,`start_date`,end_date,msg,sunday,monday,tuesday,wednesday,thursday,friday,saturday) VALUES ('1',
'2016-9-9','2016-9-9','AI','100','100','100','100','100','100','100');"

Comment: Then what's your error. You don't give the mysql error above in your comment. That's just the statement!

Answer (score 0):

Just insert as before:

```
INSERT INTO hilton(`property_id`, `sunday`, `monday`, `tuesday`, `wednesday`, `thursday`, `friday`, `saturday`)
VALUES (1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
```

See this SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/456ba/1

Probably see also: [how to insert foreign key in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17137949/how-to-insert-foreign-key-in-a-table)